# What does the FAA consider to be "good moral character"?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification

Per [14 CFR 61.153(c)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_1153) candidates for an ATP license must "be of good moral character".

What does that actually mean and how does an examiner or the FAA verify it?

Comment: I believe that cheating on an exam or lying about flight experience is considered "bad moral character".

Comment: and wouldn't be surprised if they also check criminal records for things like drugs related charges.

Comment: "When the FAA uses a wordit means just what they choose it to mean — neither more nor less." - With apologies to Humpty Dumpty :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An examiner uses the contents of FAA Order 8900.1 - Flight Standards Information Management System (FSIMS)as guidance for doing their job.

As you might imagine, there is some guidance available for them [there](http://fsims.faa.gov/WDocs/8900.1/V05%20Airman%20Cert/Chapter%2003/05_003_001Rev1.htm):

> - VOLUME 5 (AIRMAN CERTIFICATION)
> - CHAPTER 2 (TITLE 14 CFR PART 61 CERTIFICATION OF PILOTS AND FLIGHT INSTRUCTORS)
> - Section 18 (Conduct an Airline Transport Pilot Certification, Including Additional Category/Class Rating)
> - Paragraph 5-704 (ELIGIBILITY –ATP CERTIFICATE – AIRPLANE, ROTORCRAFT, AND POWERED LIFT):
> - **C. Good Moral Character Requirement:**
>     An applicant must be of good moral character. The inspector must ask an applicant if the
>     applicant has been convicted of a felony. If the applicant’s answer is
>     affirmative, the inspector should make further inquiry about the
>     nature and disposition of the conviction. If an inspector has reason
>     to believe an applicant does not qualify for an ATP certificate
>     because of questionable moral character, the inspector must not
>     conduct the practical test. Instead, the inspector will refer the
>     matter to the immediate supervisor for resolution. The supervisor may
>     need to consult with regional counsel for a determination concerning
>     whether the applicant meets the moral character eligibility
>     requirement.

That's the basic guidance that the examiners have, but there are also legal cases that have delved into this area and give more specific examples.  I found a blog which covers it in some detail at [All About Airplanes](http://allaboutairplanes.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/good-moral-character-for-airline-transport-pilots/).  Falsification of documents, embezzlement, and acting in a malicious manner towards others are cited as reasons that ATP certificates have been denied or revoked.

Comment: Multiple misdemeanor charges were disqualifying for one applicant. I believe that case is still in front of the NTSB.  The last rumor I heard was that writing bad checks and larceny may not result in denial. However multiple charges of domestic violence (misdemeanor) were considered disqualifying, however I do not have direct knowledge of that case.

Answer (score 4):

In 1994, four years after he had disposed of the last of his interests in other airlines, the FAA denied [Frank Lorenzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Lorenzo) an operating certificate for startup airline ATX, saying that Texas Air, Eastern, and Continental "experienced operational, maintenance and labor-related problems that were among the most serious in the history of U.S. aviation."

Loenzo's rejection was described in a [New York Times article dated 6 April 1994](https://www.nytimes.com/1994/04/06/business/company-news-lorenzo-plan-for-airline-is-rejected.html).

This rejection was not for the ATP certificate, but for an operating certificate (which is issued to the ATP's employer).

Comment: To make the answer more complete, is there an article that you can reference?