# Having declared a mental health condition in the past, how will this affect my plans to work as a pilot, and what should I do about it now?

Tags: medical

About a year and a half ago I moved into an apartment, where pets are not permitted. In order to be able to bring my pet with me, I applied online and obtained an "Emotional Support Animal" letter that in effect, states that my mental health is such that I am unable to live without the animal. This obliged the landlord to permit me to bring the cat with me.

The pet did provide with me emotional support during a difficult time in my life but in retrospect having it declared an emotional support animal was probably not the correct treatment but I couldn't get the building to accept me any other way. Now I'm concerned that this letter is going to be my downfall. I've never been treated or medicated for anxiety or depression, never actually met or spoke to the therapist that issued the letter. I know I have to declare mental health treatment on my medxpress form before my AME... What should I do about this ESA letter?

If this letter keeps me from flying I may never forgive myself.  I figure my best bet is to call AOPA and speak to someone in their Medical department and to schedule a consultation with an AME. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: This question seems to be about pets, declarations of mental health and truthfulness in declaring. Tag medical yes, but where is the relevance specifically for a PPL medical. Voted to close.

Comment: This is what happens when you don't think things through...

Comment: The FAA hates liars.  This is a stone cold fact.  You're not is a good position here and if this underhanded nonsense ever came to light in an investigation, any goodwill the feds may have shown you will be out the window.  You may become a commercial pilot someday but, whatever you do, DON'T F*** UP.  The feds will roast you.

Comment: @Shannon The advice here to seek expert legal opinion is undoubtedly good.  Needing "emotional support" is not necessarily mentally unhealthy at all.  What you can learn as a pilot is that when you committed to that apartment, you put yourself in that situation.  The "chain of disaster" started there.  It may have been best to divert to another apartment.  Think ahead.  Relate what you learned from it.  It might turn out ok.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is inspired by best-practices in dealing with immigration officers.

I shall not dance around your feelings.  You picked the right industry to tell that lie, because the airline industry in particular is extremely familiar with fraudulent "support animals" - people slapping a vest on Fido to sneak them where pets do not belong.  The airlines have struggled with this and its consequences, and the FAA is certainly well aware of it.

Simply **Tell The Truth** about your mental health.  Which is to say, *tell the truth **now***.

But you can't tell the truth if you don't know what is is. At extremes, stating a fact you don't know *is lying*, because you imply that you know it.

The form asks if you were **diagnosed** with a **mental disorder**.  Note those words.

The origin of the *question on the matter* is the "doctor"'s letter.  Review it.  If it plainly claims "diagnosis" and "mental disorder", then that is that: you must tick "yes". However if it is ambiguous on the point, **then you *don't know*** -- you should ask the "doctor" for clarification. I would write them and say you are applying for an ATP license, and ask them a) Did you **diagnose** me?  If so was the diagnosis of a **mental disorder** in the meaning of this form (attached)?

And the doctor will write you back and state definitively a) whether it was a diagnosis and b) whether it was of a mental disorder or other reportable thing on that form.  She will surely give you the most helpful answer possible within her medical ethics. **You may rely on that because she is a licensed professional**.  There may be an ethical issue there, but that's between her and her medical board: not your problem.

"Ah, but she can't recant the diagnosis since she's not a bona-fide doctor!"  Well then, she also was incapable of issuing a diagnosis, so you were not diagnosed after all.

If FAA asks about the contradiction between your FAA claim and your support animal letter, show them this second letter.  Of course they will suspect your goal was to cheat your landlord, but that does not violate any FAA regulations (except *perhaps* the ["morals" rule](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8530/what-does-the-faa-consider-to-be-good-moral-character), but therein, they are concerned about serious arcs of behavior that indicate disrespect for the duties of *pilot*, e.g. lying to FAA about mental health, *not* lying to landlord about a cat).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95447/discussion-on-answer-by-harper-having-declared-a-mental-health-condition-in-the).

Answer (score 5):

Problem is you've made a legal declaration (via that web site) that you have an emotional condition.  Legal enough to force a landlord to apply the exception.

Your choice is to check the box on the medical [questionnaire](https://www.aviationmedicine.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/FAA-Form-8500-8-GG-Edition-APPLICATION-FOR-AIRMAN-MEDICAL-CERTIFICATE.pdf) about "Mental disorders of any sort" **yes**, and then work your way through the system getting evaluated as no longer having a problem, or maybe convincing an AME that the original lie over a cat was no big deal and getting him/her to go along and certify you as "recovered".

Or check **no** and hope nobody finds out.  You *can* check no and it's likely no one will be the wiser, unless something happens in future like an accident that results in an investigation and *that's* when they will start digging into that kind of stuff.  And the penalty for making a false declaration is up to a quarter mil fine and 5 years, as you can see on the lower left of Page 4 of the form.  So you'll have to carry that baggage along with you over your career if you go with **no**.

Anyway, I would speak to a lawyer that handles aviation medical issues and follow his/her advice.  I certainly wouldn't proceed based on advice from anonymous nobodies like me and others on ASE.

Comment: Check "no" and further compound the problem? LOL!

Comment: Yep.  Those "letter factories" where probably 90% of the applicants are people just weaseling their way around contracts should be required to post a disclaimer that says "BTW, you are legally declaring yourself emotionally unfit for certain activities when you sign off.  Just so you know."

Comment: I think you err in your assumptions about the mechanisms of ADA and parallel laws: that disabled must make formal and public declarations to collect their rights.  Not at all. These laws are heavily tilted toward privacy.  Separately, there's doctor-patient confidentiality (not least, HIPAA).

Comment: @Harper When one signs the Med Xpress form, you give the FAA the right to get any medical records they seek. They don't often do that, but if they do, the statement about needing an ESA may well be seen as being in tension with other answers given in the FAA form, and "oh, yeah, I just lied about needing the ESA" may not be nearly adequate to resolve things. "Oh, okay, we'll ignore the statement you want us to ignore, and believe the statement you want us to believe..." isn't how the Feds operate!

Comment: This answer is the only correct one. Consulting with an AME (and an attorney, AOPA or otherwise) is an excellent idea. What an AME or attorney tells you carries actual weight. Anything we can tell you here, either "don't worry" or "you're done", isn't worth the paper it (isn't even) printed on. Something this important is worth getting a real professional's advice on, BEFORE you submit a MED X PRESS form.

Comment: @RalphJ in which case you simply get a letter from that same "doctor" saying you are fully cured and/or the disability will not conflict with flying an airplane, which cancels out the other since both have equal "credibility". Worst case FAA tells you to get a third party evaluation, which you pass.

Comment: @Harper  Unless an AME or an attorney is the one giving that advice, the OP would be ill-advised to make a potentially career-ending bet on it. ***If*** that is what the paid professional recommends, great, go with it. But until then, don't base a career on what somebody on the internet said. The OP needs to ***get actual professional advice*** on this.

Comment: @RalphJ *One of the "somebody on the Internet" people of whom you speak is this fake ADA doctor.*  I cannot advocate lying to the FAA; the question should be examined carefully.  I see  a bona-fide question of fact, as follows: whether the fake ADA doctor actually **diagnosed** OP with a **mental disorder**.  Only that same "doctor" can say definitively, so a letter from them stating whether they did or did not, should settle the question.

Comment: @Harper and on what planet are you going to get a doctor to say they signed off on a fraudulent diagnosis?  In any case she must talk to an aviation lawyer about this first.  Nobody else.

Comment: Look, you guys are being intentionally obtuse, and it's rude.  You are *pre-judging* that this "doctor" **diagnosed** and that they declared **mental disorder**.  That is not in evidence.  What is in evidence is that this is a cheap tick-the-boxes FHA "get my cat in" letter.  As far as your advice, sure on the lawyer, but ticking that box before talking to both the lawyer and the "doctor" is a big mistake.  I don't understand why the extremism and harshness.

Comment: I never said tick the box first.  I said see the lawyer first.  She made a legal declaration, made representations, to get the cat letter. Regardless how sketchy the organization is, there is a paper trail to something damaging that only a lawyer can advise her on.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few ways to handle this, and I think its important to be frank about the fact that the letter is fraudulent (by your own admission) and you have no issues that actually require an emotional support animal. Depending on how you look at that I would say that you have never had any mental health treatment since the letter was untrue (from a diagnostic standpoint) to begin with.

[The FAA covers the various paths for mental health issues on this page](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/exam_tech/item47/amd/table/) but you have no issues to begin with so again you don't really need to worry.

Furthermore the FAA does not go through or even demand to see medical records when you get your medical cert. As such if you did not report the letter they would not initially know of the incident as they do not go through your records. Generally [the FAA knows only what you tell them initially](https://pilot-protection-services.aopa.org/news/2014/april/28/your-personal-health-information-and-the-faa) so again, if you don't have an actual medical issue (which you don't) then by one way of reason it would not be incorrect to put no.

As others have mentioned if something were to happen they could go through your records and this could all come to light. It may be wise to have the letter/diagnosis officially redacted or changed. One of the nice things about the medical community is that you can always get a *second opinion* and a *third, fourth and fifth...* If you are really concerned having another doctor state that this is a non issue for you may help your case should you check yes.

Comment: "They'll never know" may well be how things play out, but John K is right about the risks one takes by relying on that. If things do unravel, and one gets caught having lied to the FAA on every medical form submitted, the situation can get bad in a hurry. DV'd because I think John K offers the much wiser answer.

Comment: @RalphJ I agree and may re-word, as the intention was, it does not appear as though they have grounds to dig into your records (unless something happens) and i still belive that because there is no actual underlying medical issue its not really lying. I guess it comes down a cascading lie situation.

Comment: That's why you have to be very careful about what the medical form actually says, juxtaposed against what the "doctor" actually said.   Easy enough to third-party that; ask the "doctor" to clarify whether s/he meant you had a -whatever the form asks - did you *diagnose* me with a *mental disorder*?  If the "doctor" replies that her earlier statement does not constitute a "diagnosis" or "mental disorder", you have properly relied on counsel of a professional, and any wrongdoing isn't yours.