# Is it possible to become a commerical pilot and have an Emotional Support Animal?

Tags: medical, pilot-certification

I was wondering this as I am trying to get an ESA while also trying to get my pilots license. I was wondering if this will interfere with my plans to becoming a pilot.

Comment: Needing an emotional support animal may indicate a disqualifying mental health condition.

Comment: Even if you could get a license, there'd be almost no air carrier that would allow it.

Comment: There was a post on here about this a couple of years ago, by someone who'd faked a problem to be able to take her pet on airline flights using the ESA rules, and now she wanted to get a pilot license and was going to have to disclose her "fake" psychological condition. A tangled web she wove for sure.  Assuming your problem is legit, it's still likely to be a problem as emotional or psychological issues are generally disqualifying, so think hard about whether an ESA is really necessary.  But check with a medical examiner.

Comment: @JohnK [This thread](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/65824/7532) is the one you're referring to. Not quite a dupe, but interesting reading. Wonder how that case turned out...

Comment: I'm going to be blunt, and it is both for your own and the good of the general public: if you have a mental condition that requires an emotional support animal to accompany you through your normal daily tasks, you are not fit for a professional pilot job.

Comment: While you mentioned being in the process of obtaining both, there are actually two different questions implied:  1. If I have been diagnosed with a mental condition requiring an ESA, will that disqualify me from a commercial pilot certificate?  2. Can I reasonably expect an air carrier to allow me to bring my ESA along while I am flying for compensation?  The answers may be different.

Comment: ... looking at it again I see a third possible interpretation from the wording of the title question:  3.  Can an ESA be a commercial pilot?  The answer to that one is a definite no.

Comment: @RalphJ oh yeah! That was to get around a rental property no-pets rule.  She didn't get much sympathy for her cynical motives in the comments lol.

Comment: @JohnK  She really didn't! If there was ever going to be a tough crowd for sympathy for somebody who (in her case, not the OP here) claimed a fake emotional support animal, airline pilots, flight attendants, & frequent fliers would be it. We saw ***so*** many pets that flew (the rule has changed a bit recently) free because nobody could question the *emotional support* status of Fluffy, that we got pretty jaded. Which hurt those with a legit need and an actual emotional support animal.  I think "hoisted on her own petard" was the chuckled commentary on her situation there!

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Which country’s regulations are you asking about? Although, even if your country’s medical regulations allow it, it would probably be very impractical.

Comment: @MichaelHall your 3rd option is the first way I read it! "Let's eat Grandma!" Commas save lives.

Comment: The ESA animal should be a gerbil.  Very easy to (ahem) hide.

Answer (score -7):

There’s no reason you can’t that I can think of. That being said, if you need an emotional support animal for day-to-day life, you may not be able to handle the stresses of flying, emergencies, etc.  And they are not gonna let you keep a dog or similar critter in the cockpit with you.

Comment: While I totally agree with your answer, “no reason I can think of” falls short of the sort of credibility this site craves.  Most medical questions here are quickly dispensed of with recommendations to seek out an AME or other medical professional.  Just an observation FWIW…

Comment: I dunno, the first sentence is a problem.  He has to check a box about mental issues "of any kind" on the medical form that he has to sign, on penalty of fines and jail time.  Emotional sensitivity or instability requiring an animal will almost certainly be disqualifying if the condition is current as  opposed to "recovered from".  If he's a vet that needs it because of PTSD, that's a real shame.

Comment: Your first sentence and the rest of your answer seem to be contradictory...

Comment: Obtaining an ESA is not against any kind of medical requirement needed for a flight physical. Now if this was prescribed by a doctor as part of a diagnosis for another mental condition, yeah I could see that.

Comment: To get an ESA with the right to take that ESA wherever you want, which is the point, you have to have a diagnosed condition.  If you have a diagnosed condition, you have to check the box on the medical form.

Comment: If a mental condition requires an ESA, it would likely disqualify an applicant from obtaining an aviation medical clearance.

Comment: “If” the reason for an ESA is a disqualifying medical condition.  This is not always the case.  People can get ESAs simply because they feel sad and lonely

Comment: @JohnK Not sure what OP's jurisdiction is, but ESAs and service animals are completely different under U.S. law. The legal right to take them wherever you want only applies to actual service animals, not ESAs. The only extra legal right for those is to have one in your home, even if your landlord bans pets.